# I am trying to integrate stripe JS payment in my project related to space renting site and i want to add recurring payments , and i am stuck there

Tags: node.js, payment

As I'm working on a storage booking project, there are multiple hosts who add multiple storages for rents, having different plan type i.e. weekly, monthly, and yearly and each has different pricing, SO when users try to book that storage, and they choose one of the plans, I want to create the subscription type based on that plan and price and do recurring payments according to the plan selected i.e. monthly, weekly or yearly which is Set by hosts. Is this possible to do with stripe js, somebody help me out. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible using Stripe's node.js API (or any other backend API). Check out the docs at https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices/object?lang=node#price_object . There is a recurring field that you can use. You can create different products and prices using Stripe dashboard or a backend API.

Comment: Is that means i can add dynamic price and products for each subscription ??

Comment: Yes @Sumitdahal, it's pretty flexible. You can create prices and products on the run.